# Defining Model attribute that's a computed value?

Tags: ember.js, properties, model, ember-data

Is there a way to define a computed property that's a DS.attribute?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you give an example (pseudo code) and maybe what you're trying to accomplish?  Are you just asking about a computed property on the Model?  Or do you want to send up the computed property up to the server as well and that's why you want to add it?

Comment: Are you potentially asking about trabsforms?